# Distinct count on multiple columns - ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I am new to ssrs and I am working on a report where I need to get a distinct count on two columns to display the total.

Table/Dataset format:

```
ID   CREATEDATE  
123  03/01/2015 11:20 pm  
123  03/01/2015 11:20 PM  
123  NULL  
123  03/20/2015 05:15 PM  
345  04/01/2015 05:20 PM
```

Datatypes:

```
ID - Int  
CreateDate - Datetime
```

If I get a distinct count on the above ex it should return 3 - First two rows have the same ID and Datetime. Eliminate Null records from the count

I tried something like following it works in all scenarios except when there is null value in a row it shows #error in the output.

> =CountDistinct((Fields!ID.Value)+(Fields!CREATEDATE.Value.ToString()))

Could anyone please suggest either how to eliminate null value in my distinct count or better way to do this. Appreciate your time and help.

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend counting at database level rather than SSRS.

Comment: handle it within the query of the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=CountDistinct(CStr(Fields!ID.Value)+CStr(Fields!CREATEDATE.Value))
```

Comment: Looks like its including Null values I am getting 4 instead of 3 in the example provided above. Is there anyway I can exclude the null values before getting the distinct count?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following and it seem to be working so far.

```
=CountDistinct(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!CREATEDATE.Value),Nothing,CStr(Fields!ID.Value)+CStr(Fields!CREATEDATE.Value)))
```